# Android Room: Is it possible to use bounded type parameters in an entity?

Tags: android, android-room, type-parameter, bounded-types, fastadapter

I am currently combining Mike Penz Fastadapter with Android Room. The expandable model class needs to be implemented like this:

```
public class MyClass<Parent extends IItem & IExpandable,
        SubItem extends IItem & ISubItem>
        extends AbstractExpandableItem<MyClass<Parent, SubItem>, MyClass.ViewHolder, SubItem> {
```

I want to use the model also as a room entity. The first problem was easy to solve - I created a custom version of AbstractExpandableItem where the fields would be annoteted with @Ignore tags to not brake the code generation. A simpler implementation of Fastadapter worked just fine this way.

However, Room seems to have a problem with bounded type parameters for entities, as it throws these compile errors in the DAO implementation:

- Error:(40, 115) error: cannot find symbol class Parent
- Error:(40, 123) error: cannot find symbol class SubItem

My DAO is:

```
    @Dao
public interface MyDAO {

    @Query("Select * from Table")
    LiveData<List<MyClass>> getAllStuff();
```

Unlike [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48845327/android-rooms-does-not-accept-generic-field-type), I could not solve my issues with an update - I put my Room gradle version on 1.1.1 and the error still happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FastAdapter also offers the possibility to define a normal `Model` class, which can be a super simple POJO and a `Item` class.

This way you can have all your data definition in the model, which will not require any parent classes or implementations, and the `Item` which will do the UI binding.

A simple example can be found in the sample application of the `FastAdapter`.

Instead of an `ItemAdapter` you will use a `ModelAdapter`, and then you provide the logic on how your model converts to a `Item`.

This can be as simple as:

```
ModelAdapter<IconModel, ModelIconItem> itemAdapter = new ModelAdapter<>(new IInterceptor<IconModel, ModelIconItem>() {
        @Override
        public ModelIconItem intercept(IconModel iconModel) {
            return new ModelIconItem(iconModel);
        }
});
```

For this simple sample the model looks like:

```
public class IconModel {
    public IIcon icon;

    public IconModel(IIcon icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

And the item looks like this:

```
public class ModelIconItem extends ModelAbstractItem<com.mikepenz.fastadapter.app.model.IconModel, ModelIconItem, ModelIconItem.ViewHolder> {
    public ModelIconItem(com.mikepenz.fastadapter.app.model.IconModel icon) {
        super(icon);
    }
    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return R.id.fastadapter_model_icon_item_id;
    }
    @Override
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.icon_item;
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(ViewHolder viewHolder, List<Object> payloads) {
        super.bindView(viewHolder, payloads);

        ... bind logic
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder getViewHolder(View v) {
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
    protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected View view;
        @BindView(R.id.name)
        public TextView name;
        @BindView(R.id.icon)
        public IconicsImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
            this.view = view;
        }
    }
}
```

The full sample code can be found here:
https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/fastadapter/app/ModelItemActivity.java#L51

Comment: Thank you very much for answering in person, this was exactly the advice I needed :) Splitting up item and model is the way to go for Room. Your library rocks!